# $\sigma$ additivity and continous from below/above for a measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $X:= \mathbb Q, \quad\mathbb H:= \{[a,b) \cap \mathbb Q | a,b \in \mathbb R\} , \quad \mu([a,b) \cap \mathbb Q) := b-a$ for $a \le b$.

I showed that $\mathbb H$ generates the borel set of $2^{\mathbb Q}$.
Now i am having trouble on proving or disproving the following properties for $\mu$.

1) $\sigma$ additivity

2) continous from below and above

3) continous from above in $\emptyset$

I know that if I prove 1) then 2) + 3) follow aswell, but i am having big troubles with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathcal A=\sigma(\mathbb H)$ then for every element $q\in\mathbb Q$: $$\{q\}=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\left[q,q+\frac1n\right)\cap\mathbb Q \right)\in\mathcal A$$ and consequently $\mathcal A=\wp(\mathbb Q)$ since every subset of $\mathbb Q$ is countable union of singletons.

If we assume that $\mu$ is a measure on $\sigma(\mathbb H)$ then we will encounter a contradiction.

For every $q\in\mathbb Q$ and every $\epsilon>0$ we have $\{q\}\subseteq[q+\epsilon)\cap\mathbb Q$ so that: $$\mu(\{q\})\leq\mu([q,q+\epsilon)\cap\mathbb Q)=\epsilon$$and consequently $\mu(\{q\})=0$.

This however leads to: $$\mu([a,b)\cap\mathbb Q)=\sum_{q\in[a,b)\cap Q}\mu(\{q\})=0$$